# Inserting matrix values into SQL

Tags: sql

I have encountered this problem with both Python and R (and it can be generalised to most languages with SQL bindings).

I have a matrix a values `matrix` and labels `xlabels`, `ylabels` such that `matrix[i][j]` refers to a record specified by `xlabels[i]` and `ylables[j]`. If I want to insert (or update) into an SQL database, I generally do something as follows

```
for i in 1:len(xlabels):
    for j in 1:len(ylabels):
        insert_into_db(xlabels[i], ylabels[j], matrix[i][j])
```

However this is normally very slow. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Maybe writing the operation as a large query in a text file and running that.

Comment: I think you can use `XML` ;).

Comment: Have you tried beginning a transaction before your outer loop and committing when the outer loop completes?  If the data set is very large you could alternatively try beginning a transaction before each iteration of your outer loop and committing after each completion of your inner loop.